# Listed on spamcop.bl.net - why?

Tags: postfix, spam

I entered our mailserver IP and got this report:

```
In the past 5.4 days, it has been listed 3 times for a total of 3.6 days
```

How would I go about determining what caused my server to get flagged? Does this imply that one of the email addresses is sending spam?

Comment: It implies that someone reported you for messages sent from your server. Some RBLs also have spam-trap addresses, if your mailserver sends to one of those addresses, you are listed.

Comment: Oh dear. So this is likely a permanent thing unless I can figure out either what sort of messages are being flagged or which 'spam-trap' address is being sent to. **dang**.

Comment: First thing to check, mailing list software.. also things like spam checking messages unless they come from SASL authenticated senders can help a lot.

Comment: No, most blacklists have a system or set of procedures in place for you to follow once you've plugged the leak. It's not a walk in the park, but you're not doomed forever more.

Comment: So i've established that my server isn't an open relay. So either someone has inadvertently sent email to a spam-trap or there is a bot running on someone's machine?

Comment: Yeah, and I'd vote for the bot, myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple sites that will run an automated suite of tests against your mailserver for problems, like this:

```
   http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx
```

and there are other sites that will check a mail server's IP address against the reverse-block-lists (RBLs).

```
   http://www.rbl-check.com/
```

If you're listed on an RBL, you're almost always given a URL to visit with the details of your transgression.

I'd submit your mail server to both of those.

Comment: It appears that I'm listed on two of these. One doesn't tell me why but the other says email was sent to a spam-trap.

Answer (score 5):

How you end up on a spam-reporting blocking list depends on the list involved.  In SpamCop's case, SpamCop's users (people who get their mail service, and people who have reporting accounts with them) report the spam they receive.  Sometimes people get "happy" and report things that aren't spam, but if you've had three reports in the last week it's possible/probable that something that went out from your server is hinky.  SpamCop probably has a link or other information that will let you know what the offending items were and/or how to get off the list.

Other things to check:

1. I assume your server is not an open relay.  If it is, close it up.
2. On more than one occasion with more than one employer, we've ended up on a blocking list because someone brought an infected laptop onto our premises, or one of our users got a spambot virus.  Make sure that your users' workstations are clean.
3. If it does turn out that one of your users is intentionally doing something they shouldn't with your resources, show no mercy.  S/he is endangering the communications of the entire company.  That said, I personally have not seen this, although I'm sure it happens.

Good luck!